# How can I create a space between two components in a JPanel

Tags: java, layout, jpanel

I am trying to create a space between an `ImageIcon` and a `JButton`, which are placed in the same `JPanel` side by side.

This is what I have so far:

```
allPanels.add(middlePanel);
middlePanel.add(grassPanel);
grassPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(grassPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS)); 
grassPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("grass.jpg")));
buyGrass = new JButton("Buy Food");
grassPanel.add(buyGrass);
```

Is there anyway to separate the image  and the button, so that the image is more to the left and the button is more to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`Box.createHorizontalStrut(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createHorizontalStrut%28int%29).  This will add an empty area, e. g.:

```
grassPanel.add(new JLabel(...));
grassPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
grassPanel.add(buyGrass);
```

Comment: It is giving unnecessary vertical space, I want only Horizantal Space.